# How can I get readr to handle quoted NA values?

Tags: r, readr

```
library(readr)

csv <- 'x,y
"1","N/A"
"N/A","2"
'

df <- read_csv(csv, col_types = "ii", na=c("\"N/A\"", "N/A"))
```

Running this yields:

```
> df <- read_csv(csv, col_types = "ii", na=c("\"N/A\"", "N/A"))
Warning: 2 parsing failures.
row col   expected actual
  1   y an integer    N/A
  2   x an integer    N/A
```

Practically, the `"N/A"` values end up as `NA`, but is there a more elegant way to handle this? For example, this runs without issues, illustrating the desired behaviour.

```
csv2 <- 'x,y
"1",N/A
N/A,"2"
'

df2 <- read_csv(csv2, col_types = "ii", na="N/A")
```

Comment: I get some warning in the first case, but it reads it as NA.

Comment: I know it ends up as `NA`. But when I see `Warning: 296656 parsing failures`, it would be nice to suppress the warnings for non-issues (i.e., `"N/A"` being converted to `NA`).

Comment: I don't know whether it is possible within the `read_csv`, but you can do `read_csv(gsub('"', "", csv), col_types = "ii", na = "N/A")`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is a [known issue](https://github.com/hadley/readr/issues/295) that has been addressed in the (current) development version of `readr`. So doing this addresses the issue:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("hadley/readr")
```